# kestrel-hellomvc.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/dotnet: No such process

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core, systemd

I was following the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction on publishing asp.net core project on Nginx, the previous steps all seem successful, but while

```
systemctl start kestrel-hellomvc.service
systemctl status kestrel-hellomvc.service
```

I got

```
kestrel-hellomvc.service - Example .NET Web API Application running on Ubuntu
   
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-hellomvc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-04-24 03:12:42 UTC; 8s ago
Process: 4285 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/84999/Demo4/Demo4.dll (code=exited, status=217/USER)
Main PID: 4285 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Apr 24 03:12:42 instance-5 systemd[1]: Started Example .NET Web API Application running on Ubuntu.
Apr 24 03:12:42 instance-5 systemd[4285]: kestrel-hellomvc.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/dotnet: No such process
Apr 24 03:12:42 instance-5 systemd[1]: kestrel-hellomvc.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Apr 24 03:12:42 instance-5 systemd[1]: kestrel-hellomvc.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 24 03:12:42 instance-5 systemd[1]: kestrel-hellomvc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anyone know the solution, it seems I don't have the `/usr/bin/dotnet` folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved the problem, the source folder owner should be `www-data`, having 755 permission. The Apache user is called `www-data` on Ubuntu, and `apache` on CentOS. So specifically set `User=www-data` in `kestrel-hellomvc.service` if running on Ubuntu, thanks to Jeppe's comment.

Also, if you have added users in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` before, removing these users might resolve this issue as well.

Comment: The Apache user is called `www-data` on Ubuntu, and `apache` on CentOS. So specifically set `User=www-data` in `kestrel-hellomvc.service` if running on Ubuntu.

Comment: I run on Centos, changing from `www-data` to `apache` works for me.

Answer (score 9):

In file /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service, I had added user. The issue got resolved when I removed the user.

```
...

[Service]
User="someuser"
...
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1156676/what-causes-systemd-failed-at-step-user-spawning-usr-sbin-opendkim-no-such-p

Comment: Default user is `root` FWIW :)

Answer (score 3):

After many hours, the answer for me was "yum reinstall systemd"

Comment: Worked for me, got the error when using journalctl -xe

Comment: Did this install a newer version perhaps? An update?

Answer (score 2):

The same error message will be displayed if the user defined in your service file does not exist, regardless of the permission on the web app folder.

Comment: This is it! If you copy and paste generic `.service` files remember to update the `User=...` in `[Service]` section. Thanks.